# free(): double free detected in tcache 2 - c realloc error

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Im trying to save a file of words (max length 100 chars but I don't know how many), by storing pointers to the words in a char **. I start by allocating memory for 100 pointers and counting the words i save. If there are more then 100 words in the file i start reallocating memory with space for one more pointer every time i read a new word from file. Then i allocate space for the actual characters of the word.

```
    // init wordlist for 100 words
    char **mywords = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
    int wordcount = 0;
    char **word_pointer = mywords;
    while(!feof(wordlist))
    {
        // dynamically reallocate more memory if we have more than 100 words
        if (wordcount >= 100) {
            realloc(mywords, sizeof(char*) * (wordcount+1));
        }
        char *new_word = *word_pointer;
        new_word = malloc(101 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(new_word, 101, wordlist);
        printf("%s", new_word);
        word_pointer++;
        wordcount++;
    }
```

I tested the code with a file of over 300 words and i get the error
`free(): double free detected in tcache 2`
I guess it's because of the malloc after the realloc? But I'm not sure how to fix it.

EDIT

I changed the loop to this:

```
// init wordlist for 100 words
    char **mywords = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
    int wordcount = 0;
    char **word_pointer = mywords;
    char *current_line = malloc(101 * sizeof(char));
    int max_length = 101;

    while(fgets(current_line, max_length, wordlist))
    {
        // dynamically reallocate more memory if we have more than 100 words
        if (wordcount >= 100) {
            mywords = realloc(mywords, sizeof(char*) * (wordcount+1));
        }
        *word_pointer = current_line;
        word_pointer++;
        wordcount++;
    }
```

And it runs without errors. But my concern is that `word_pointer` will, after ever call of `realloc()` point to where the mywords list was before right? How do i change it so that after inserting e.g. 120 words, the realloc happens, that it points to the new mywords+120 so that i can keep inserting pointers?

Comment: You have a complicated scenario where you are passing a pointer value around your variables, but after the `realloc`, your `char **word_pointer = mywords;` may no longer be pointing into the reallocated array, which may have been moved elsewhere in memory. I suggest you index into `mywords` more directly and not use the out-of-date value `word_pointer`

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) It is idiomatic to drive an input loop with the return value from `fgets`. So all-in-all I suggest you restructure that code.

Comment: ...looking again, I see you are not after all using `char **word_pointer`. You assign its target to `char *new_word` which you immediatley overwrite with `malloc`. But then, you are not storing this allocated pointer in the pointer array `char **mywords`. So the error may be coming when you attempt to print the data you input. But my other comment stands: it's rather messy and needs a fresh approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are ignoring the return value of realloc, which is pointer to the allocated memory.

In this case, realloc may be extending block of already given memory (if it is possible) or, otherwise, allocate a completely new block of memory and copy given input.

I think

```
mywords = realloc(mywords, sizeof(char*) * (wordcount+1));
```

Should do the trick.

Also, reallocating, as I mentioned, is not very optimal. Notice that anytime you come across a new word realloc has to find a spot in memory and copy a whole block of data. So, supposedly, given a file with 300 words your program copies your array 200 times.

I think it would be much better to scan the file first, counting all the words and then use fseek to move the indicator to the beginning. After that allocate array for your words and scan the file.

Answer (score 1):

Right after editing the original question I came up with the solution. I just had to add the line `word_pointer = mywords + wordcount;` below the call to `realloc()`

Thanks for your help!